# Bloodhound does not cache data from remote fetches in local storage

Tags: caching, local-storage, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I am trying to load autocompletion information of people's names for typeahead and then not have to query the server again if I already have a result.

For example if i search a person's name and the data for that person (among others) gets retrieved from a remote query, when I delete the name and search for the surname instead I want to have the previously cached names with that surname to show up. What actually happens is that the results are again retrieved from the server and the suggested.

Caching only works while typing a single word ("Mic" -> "Mich" -> "Micha" -> "Michael").

TL;DR: I want to cache results from bloodhound in Local Storage not only from prefetch (which cannot be applied to my situation) but from remote as well and use that before querying remote again.

What i currently have is

```
function dispkey(suggestion_object){
  console.log(suggestion_object);
  return suggestion_object["lastname"] + ", " + suggestion_object["firstname"];
}

var engine = new Bloodhound({
  name: 'authors',
  local: [],
  remote: 'http://xxxxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxx?query=%%QUERY',
  datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
  },
  queryTokenizer: function (s){
    return s.split(/[ ,]+/);
  },
});

engine.initialize();

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    hint: true,
    minLength: 3,
},
{
  displayKey: dispkey,
  templates: {
     suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
      '<p id="author_autocomplete_email_field" >{{email}}</p>',
      '<p id="author_autocomplete_name_field">{{lastname}} {{firstname}}</p>',
      ].join(''))},
  source: engine.ttAdapter(),
});
```

I haven't found something similar and i am afraid there is no trivial solution to this.

P.S.: I also noticed that datumTokenizer never gets called

```
datumTokenizer: function(d) {
    console.log("Lalalalala");
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.val);
  },
```

when i used this, "Lalalalala" was never outputted in the chrome debug console.

Comment: It's not possible to have remote suggestions saved to local storage right now unless you want to fork typeahead.js. If this is something you think the project should support, I'd suggest opening a feature request. Oh, and the `datumTokenizer` isn't used for remote suggestions, it's only used when retrieving suggestions from loaded through local and prefetch.

Comment: Will do, thanks for the advice. You could use your comment as the answer since that was exactly what i wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [jharding](https://stackoverflow.com/users/393075/jharding) mentioned it's not possible to have remote suggestions pulled from `localstorage` at this point.

However, I recently worked on a small project where I needed to store previous form inputs for future use in typeahead.js. To do this I saved an array of form input values to `localstorage`.

```
var inputs = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4'];
localStorage.setItem('values', JSON.stringify(inputs));
```

I then retrieved the array for use in the typeahead field.

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('values'));
$('input').typeahead({
    minLength: 3,
    highlight: true,
},
{
    name: 'data',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: this.substringMatcher(data)
});
```

You can view my [full source here](https://github.com/brettdewoody/url-builder/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/url_builder.js.jsx).

Comment: One caveat here (i think please correct if not correct) is that it will work whenever the user refreshes the page. The solutions would be to reinitialise typeahead/bloodhound every time new cache data was added, but it sounds a bit like a hack

Comment: Also there is no trivial way of checking the age of the localstorage, if you keep appending to it new data. So you need to device a clever scheme with the names of localstorage items to keep the data fresh. But, alas, your solution Brett is pretty good and I think whoever needs such functionality can work with it.

Comment: [@Makis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1150636/makis-tsantekidis) - my full solution will work after a page refresh since it uses `localstorage`. If you needed to weight or prioritize the autosuggested strings it might be possible to store them with a date key and use that in matching algorithm.